# Change input address and postcode by latlng mouse over then klick in distance matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

My first aplication about distance matrix to calculate distance. The first If load script are text box auto input by postcode after identify my ISP location. That textbox can input address or postcode to put my realy location after klick button submit query. Marker for my addres or my postcode show. And then with Parse xml with jQuery can show distance every destination.

Now I wil make change how to put my location by mouse over and then If klick in map I will get latlng and location address to process distance matrik AS origin.

This my First code: ( THANKS BEFORE )

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.storeLocator = function (options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        'mapDiv': 'map',
        'listDiv': 'list',
        'formID': 'user-location',
        'pinColor': 'fe7569',
        'startPinColor': '66bd4a',
        'pinTextColor': '000000',
        'storeLimit': 10,
        'distanceAlert': 500,
        'xmlLocation': 'data/suplier.xml',
        'addressErrorMsg': 'Please enter valid address address or postcode',
        'googleDistanceMatrixDestinationLimit': 25,
        'defaultLat': 49.719330,
        'defaultLng': -2.214539,
        'defaultLocationName': 'Northampton, United Kingdom'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        // global array of shop objects
        var _locationset = new Array();
        var geocoder;

        // Calculate distances from passed in origin to all locations in the [_locationset] array
        // using Google Maps Distance Matrix Service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DistanceMatrixService
        var GeoCodeCalc = {};
        GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistanceGoogle = function (origin, callback) {
            var destCoordArr = new Array();
            var subFunctionTokens = [];

            $.each(_locationset, function (ix, loc) {
                destCoordArr.push(loc.LatLng);
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < destCoordArr.length; i = i + settings.googleDistanceMatrixDestinationLimit) { // Google Distance Matrix allows up to 25 destinations to be passed in
                var tempArr = destCoordArr.slice(i, Math.min(i + settings.googleDistanceMatrixDestinationLimit));
                subFunctionTokens.push(this.CallGoogleDistanceMatrix(i, origin, tempArr));
            }

            $.when.apply($, subFunctionTokens)
                  .then(function () {
                      callback(true);
                  });
        };

        GeoCodeCalc.CallGoogleDistanceMatrix = function (startIndex, origin, destinations) {
            var token = $.Deferred();
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                  origins: [origin],
                  destinations: destinations,
                  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                  unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL
              }, function (response, status) {
                  if (response && response.rows.length) {
                      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
                      $.each(results, function (j, val) {
                          if (results[j].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                              _locationset[startIndex + j].Distance = GoogleMapDistanceTextToNumber(results[j].distance.text);
                         }
                      });

                      token.resolve();
                  }
              });

            return token.promise();
        };

        // Converts "123.45 mi" into 123.45
        function GoogleMapDistanceTextToNumber(str) {
            return Number(str.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
        }

        // removes Google Maps URL unfriendly chars from a string
        function formatGoogleMapUrlString(str) {
            return str.replace("&", "%26").replace(" ", "+");
        }

        //Geocode function for the origin location
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        function GoogleGeocode() {
            this.geocode = function (address, callbackFunction) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var result = {};
                        result.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        result.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        result.formatted_address = results[0].formatted_address;
                        result.address_components = results[0].address_components;
                        callbackFunction(result);
                    } else {
                        handleError("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        callbackFunction(null);
                    }
                });
            };

            this.geocodeLatLng = function (LatLng, callbackFunction) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'location': LatLng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
                        callbackFunction(results[0]);
                    } else {
                        handleError("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        callbackFunction(null);
                    }
                });
            };
        }

        //Process form input
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('submit', '#' + settings.formID, function (e) {
                $("#lblError").html("");
                //Stop the form submission
                e.preventDefault();
                //Get the user input and use it
                var userinput = $('form').serialize();
                userinput = userinput.replace("address=", "");
                if (userinput == "") {
                    handleError(settings.addressErrorMsg);
                }

                var g = new GoogleGeocode();
                var address = userinput;
                g.geocode(address, function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        showAddress(data);
                        mapping(data.latitude, data.longitude);
                    } else {
                        //Unable to geocode
                        handleError(settings.addressErrorMsg);
                    }
                });

                //Replace spaces in user input
                userinput = formatGoogleMapUrlString(userinput);
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Try HTML5 geolocation
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    //map.setCenter(pos);
                    var g = new GoogleGeocode();
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                    g.geocodeLatLng(latlng, function (address) {
                        if (address) {
                            showAddress(address);
                        } else {
                            //Unable to geocode
                            handleNoGeolocation('Error: Unable to geocode address');
                        }
                    });

                    // do the mapping stuff
                    mapping(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                }, function () {
                    handleNoGeolocation("Tracking of location was not allowed.");
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleNoGeolocation(false);
            }
        });

        function showAddress(address) {
            $("#lblAddress").html(address.formatted_address);
            // find a postcode and show it in the address textbox
            $.each(address.address_components, function (i, val) {
                if (val.types[0] == "postal_code") {
                    $("#address").val(val.short_name);
                    return false; // breaks the each() loop
                }
            });
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(error) {
            if (error) {
                var content = error;
            } else {
                var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
            }

            handleError(content + " Using default location.");
            mapping(settings.defaultLat, settings.defaultLng);
            $("#lblAddress").html(settings.defaultLocationName);

        }

        function handleError(error) {
            $("#lblError").html(error);
        }

        //Now all the mapping stuff
        function mapping(orig_lat, orig_lng) {
            $(function () {
                //Parse xml with jQuery
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: settings.xmlLocation,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (xml) {
                        _locationset = new Array();
                        $(xml).find('Placemark').each(function (i) {
                            var shop = {
                                Name: $(this).find('name').text(),
                                //Take the lat lng from the user, geocoded above
                                LatLng: new google.maps.LatLng(
                                    $(this).find('coordinates').text().split(",")[1],
                                    $(this).find('coordinates').text().split(",")[0]),
                                Description: $(this).find('description').text(),
                                Ongkir:$(this).find('ongkir').text(),
                                Muat:$(this).find('muat').text(),
                                Item:$(this).find('item').text(),
                                Kirim: (($(this).find('item').text())/($(this).find('muat').text())),
                                Marker: null,
                                Distance: null
                            };
                            _locationset.push(shop);
                        });

                        // Calc Distances from user's location
                        GeoCodeCalc.CalcDistanceGoogle(new google.maps.LatLng(orig_lat, orig_lng), function (success) {
                            if (!success) { //something went wrong
                                handleError("Unable to calculate distances at this time");
                            }
                            else {
                                //Sort the multi-dimensional array numerically
                                _locationset.sort(function (a, b) {
                                    return ((a.Distance < b.Distance) ? -1 : ((a.Distance > b.Distance) ? 1 : 0));
                                });

                                // take "N" closest shops
                                _locationset = _locationset.slice(0, settings.storeLimit);

                                //Check the closest marker
                                if (_locationset[0].Distance > settings.distanceAlert) {
                                    handleError("Unfortunately, our closest location is more than " + settings.distanceAlert + " miles away.");
                                }

                                //Create the map with jQuery
                                $(function () {
                                    var orig_LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(orig_lat, orig_lng);
                                    //Google maps settings
                                    var myOptions = {
                                        center: orig_LatLng,
                                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                    };

                                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(settings.mapDiv), myOptions);
                                    //Create one infowindow to fill later
                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                    //Add user location marker
                                    var marker = createMarker(orig_LatLng, "0", settings.startPinColor);
                                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
                                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                                    bounds.extend(orig_LatLng);

                                    $("#" + settings.listDiv).empty();

                                    $(_locationset).each(function (i, location) {
                                        bounds.extend(location.LatLng);
                                        letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i);
                                        location.Marker = createMarker(location.LatLng, letter, settings.pinColor);
                                        create_infowindow(location);
                                        listClick(letter, location);
                                    });

                                    // zoom in/out to show all markers
                                    map.fitBounds(bounds);

                                    function listClick(letter, shop) {


                                        $('<li />').html("<div class=\"list-details\"><div class=\"list-content\">"
                                        + "<div class=\"list-label\">" + letter + "<\/div>"
                                        + "<div class=\"loc-name\">" + shop.Name + "<\/div> <div class=\"loc-addr\">" + shop.Description + "<\/div>Muat " + shop.Muat + " <div class=\"loc-addr\">Rp." + shop.Ongkir + " per Km<\/div>  "
                                        +  (shop.Distance ? "<div class=\"loc-addr2\"><i>Jarak Tempuh.  "+Math.ceil(shop.Distance*1.6) + "Km</i><\/br>"+ Math.ceil(shop.Kirim) + " Kali Angkut <\/br><\/br>ONGKOS KIRIM <input type=\"text\" readonly=\"readonly\" size=\"20\" name=\"jarak\" value=\"Rp. "+Math.ceil((shop.Distance * shop.Ongkir*1.6) * Math.ceil(shop.Kirim)) + "\" /><\/div>" : "")


                                        + "<div class=\"loc-web\"><a href=\"http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr="
                                        + formatGoogleMapUrlString($("#address").val()) + "+%40" + orig_lat + "," + orig_lng
                                        + "&daddr=" + formatGoogleMapUrlString(shop.Name) + "+%40" + shop.LatLng.lat() + "," + shop.LatLng.lng()
                                        + "&hl=en" + "\" target=\"_blank\">&gt;Get directions</a><\/div><\/div><\/div>")
                                        .click(function () {
                                            create_infowindow(shop, "left");
                                        }).appendTo("#" + settings.listDiv);

                                    };

                                    //Custom marker function - aplhabetical
                                    function createMarker(point, letter, pinColor) {
                                        //Set up pin icon with the Google Charts API for all of our markers
                                        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=" + letter + "|" + pinColor + "|" + settings.pinTextColor,
                                          new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                                          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                                          new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
                                        var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
                                          new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
                                          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                                          new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

                                        //Create the markers
                                        return new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: point,
                                            map: map,
                                            icon: pinImage,
                                            shadow: pinShadow,
                                            draggable: false
                                        });
                                    };

                                    //Infowindows
                                    function create_infowindow(shop, listLocation) {
                                        var formattedAddress = "<div class=\"infoWindow\"><b>" + shop.Name + "<\/b>"
                                        + "<div>" + shop.Description + "<\/div>"
                                        + (shop.Distance ? "<div><i>" + shop.Distance + " miles<\/i><\/div><\/div>" : "<\/div>");

                                        //Opens the infowindow when list item is clicked
                                        if (listLocation == "left") {
                                            infowindow.setContent(formattedAddress);
                                            infowindow.open(shop.Marker.get(settings.mapDiv), shop.Marker);
                                        }
                                        //Opens the infowindow when the marker is clicked
                                        else {
                                            google.maps.event.addListener(shop.Marker, 'click', function () {
                                                infowindow.setContent(formattedAddress);
                                                infowindow.open(shop.Marker.get(settings.mapDiv), shop.Marker);
                                            })
                                        }
                                    };
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but if what you want is to be able to add a marker by clicking the map and then lunch the distance calculation what you have to do is to add a click event listener to the map and do what you have to do there.

Consider the following exemple (change YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY for your own key in order to be able to run the demo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY&sensor=false">
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map-container
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-width:500px;
            min-height:300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="map-container">
        Div map
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var map;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-container")[0], mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (mouseEvent) {
                var origin = mouseEvent.latLng;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: origin });
                marker.setMap(map);

                //console.log("map clicked");
                // your logic ......
                // returnFromCalcDistanceGoogle(origin, callback);
                // your logic ......

            });
        });

        function returnFromCalcDistanceGoogle() {
            // your logic ......
        }   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is not what your trying to do, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like that Mr.sabotero . .. but i will use this in my first application that. When I klick the map LatLng can input in my textbox with id="address" to submit query. Before the textbox with id="address" just work if input by addres and postcode. Now I want LatLang can input and process in textbox with id="address"

```
<div id="form-input">
            <label for="address">
                Masukan Lokasi Anda</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="" class="input-medium search-query" />
        </div>
        <div id="submit-btn">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning" /></div>
```

1. input postscode or address
2. Klick submit Query
3. Marker Origin show with color green

NOW I wont,
1. klick map
2. textbox get latlng or addres
3. submit query

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you question. Could you please Edit and make a todo list like: 1. click map. 2. Add Marker. 3. Click button ...
Could you do that please?